# Connecting to mySQL db using php error checking

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the script below on my browser all that prints out is 0:  If I erase MySQL_errno I get nothing.  How would I get a more detailed error?

```
 <?php
  $link = mysql_connect("192...", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("visitors_tables");

  echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
  echo mysql_error();
   $query = "SELECT * FROM visitors";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     foreach ($line as $value)
       {
     print "$value\n";
  }
  }
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You can start by not using the `mysql_*()` functions in your script.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't getting an error. But since `mysql_errno()` and `mysql_error()` is in no condition, it gets echoed anyway.

You can do it like this:

```
function showError($link) {
    return mysql_errno($link).': '.mysql_error($link);
}

$link = mysql_connect("192...", "root", "") or die(showError($link));
mysql_select_db("visitors_tables") or die(showError($link));
//etc.
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(showError($link));
```

`or ...;` only gets called when there actually is an error.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to test that my script is ok.  It looks like the error is in my android code. On to the next problem

Answer (score 0):

try using the below code. & insert the column_name you want to fetch at `echo $line['column_name']`

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect("192...", "root", "");
  if($link){
    mysql_select_db("visitors_tables");
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM visitors";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $line['column_name']
  }
mysql_close($link);
?>
```